# How to make your app available in UIActivityViewcontroller listed activities

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

How to make your app available in `UIActivityViewcontroller` listed activities.

Im unable to find the exact name of this feature.

Here is what I wanna do. My app is a social app where whenever other apps will share the content in `UIActivityViewController` I want my app to appear in the activities list.

I Apologise that I have no idea about what it is called. Anyone can please help me out.

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: @mitulmarsonia Actually you got confused. I want to make my app listed in  activities when ever any app tries to share the text or image like Facebook and twitter .. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's called App Extension, you can use share extensions to share the data between the extension and your app. For more information refer the [App Extensions Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html)