# How to add app in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-extensions

I am developing one app in that user can upload video to our server. Now I want to add my app in `UIActivityViewController` so from gallery user can select video and open my app so it will directly upload to my server from gallery itself.

How can I add my app to `UIActivityViewController`? Like Facebook, Vimeo and YouTube in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I have write below code in info.plist file but it’s not showing in the app!

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.video</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248246/how-to-make-your-app-available-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-listed-activities) but I do not understand how to do that.

Comment: its called Share-extension

Comment: @NitinGohel Thanks any idea how can I do that?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/

Comment: @NitinGohel After adding ShareExtenison it's showing app. Can I open my app once user click on app icon?

Comment: please do search and studing also there is example code so let studing in and try by your self

Answer (score 0):

Try using `public.movie` instead of `public.video` and also add a `CFBundleTypeRole` key.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```