# Trying to get my app to show in the "open in menu" or "import with menu"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to get my app to show in the "open in menu" or "import with menu", In the image below, I am using the native "photos" app and trying to share a selected picture.

Please help me.

[image]

I have added these into my info.plist

```
<array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>com.myapp.common-data</string>
          <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
          <array>
              <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt</string>
              <string>public.item</string>
              <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
              <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
              <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
              <string>public.image</string>
              <string>public.content</string>
             <string>public.composite-content</string>
             <string>public.archive</string>
             <string>public.audio</string>
             <string>public.movie</string>
             <string>public.text</string>
             <string>public.data</string>
         </array>
     </dict>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268508/i-need-to-show-my-app-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-for-all-applications-as-action

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396152/how-to-add-app-in-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Oh... yes the "share extension" thank you guys.